# Control the order of the colour based on the values of another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to control the order of  the colour of points/lines based on the values of another variable.

An example to explain what I am wanting to do:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345) 

# example data 
df <- data.frame(
  country = rep(c("India", "Sweden", "Germany", "Finland", "NZ", "Aus"), each = 4),
  year = rep(2010:2013, 6),
  value = sample(1:100, 24)
)

# create a rank column
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(value, ties.method = "random")) 

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(year, rank, color = country)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(direction = 1) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

The viridis colour palette is ordered, by default the ordering has been set based on the alphabetical order of the colour variable (countires), e.g. Aus darkest (purple) to Sweden lightest (yellow).

Is there a way to change the colours to be ordered based on the variable `rank` in 2010 e.g. India = darkest (Purple) to Finland lightest (Yellow)?

In my real dataset there are many more than 6 countries so I don't want to manually assign colours to country levels.

Comment: Use `aes(year, rank, color = forcats::fct_reorder(country, rank, first))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you. Basically, you want to make your country names an ordered factor.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345) 

# example data 
df <- data.frame(
  country = rep(c("India", "Sweden", "Germany", "Finland", "NZ", "Aus"), each = 4),
  year = rep(2010:2013, 6),
  value = sample(1:100, 24)
)

# create a rank column
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(value, ties.method = "random")) %>%
  arrange(year, rank) %>%
  # Arranging first is important because as_factor creates a factor ordered
  # by the order in which the values appear in the dataframe
  mutate(country = as_factor(country))

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(year, rank, color = country)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(direction = 1) +
  scale_y_reverse()
```